# OpenCV & MoviePy - Analyzing video frames

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, python-tesseract, moviepy

I've been using *OpenCV* and *MoviePy* to get images out of a video (1 image per second) and once extracted, I analyze the image with *pytesseract*. The part where the script extract images takes quite a bit of time. Is it possible or is there a function that I've overlooked in *MoviePy* or *OpenCV* that allows video frames to be analyzed without having to create images first? This could tremendously speed up the process.

Current steps:

1. Scan and extract 1fps with a specific video as argument
2. From each of those images, perform analysis on a specific area

Desired:

1. Perform analysis on a specific area of the video itself at 1 fps.

If this function exists, please inform me. Otherwise, would there be a workaround for this? Suggestions?

Thanks!!

Comment: cv.VideoCapture, determine frame rate, drop frames you don't need, ...

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz It seems like your reply has been cutout. I can't read pass ", ..."

Comment: Can you explain the reason you use MoviePy? OpenCV must be enough for that.

Comment: You can use iter_frames to get an iterator of images as RGB pixel values without saving them to image files first.  for frame in VideoFileClip('myvideo.mp4').iter_frames().  You may need to convert the resulting arrays for tesseract.  

https://zulko.github.io/moviepy/ref/VideoClip/VideoClip.html#moviepy.video.VideoClip.VideoClip.iter_frames